# Why does RuntimeException extend Exception and not the other way?

Tags: java, exception

I can imagine situation in which I'd want to catch only the checked exceptions and not the unchecked ones. I can't really imagine doing it the other way.

Comment: Exception is the superclass of **all** exceptions

Comment: The answer to this is for the purposes of this forum tautological: It was designed this way because the designers of Java designed it as such

Comment: Andrew, Yes, and I ask why not RuntimeException. @ControlAltDel Yes, and I ask why they did designed it this way.

Comment: If you understood my previous comment Atom, you would understand that I've already answered this

Comment: But does it prevent you from trying to read Java creators minds'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The checked exceptions must be caught or thrown again or your code cannot compile. So throughout your code you have to handle each one of them explicitly anyway (throw or catch) .

**And for why there is no common parent for only the checked exceptions:**

they want you to handle each one explicitly .

think of yourself writing a method and you made this method throw a checked exception. when you do that you expect the user of the method to explicitly handle this exception with code for this exception (If you didnt care about the user of your function handling the exception you would throw runtime exception (unchecked)).

So the whole idea of checked exception it is a contract between the function creator and the user that force the user to handle this exception.

Comment: ...or at least to name them explicitly in java 7 multicatch. It makes sense. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html

Answer (score 2):

I will try to give you a very precise answer, because I expect that you already have idea about [checked vs non-checked exceptions](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/checked-vs-unchecked-exception-in-java.html). 
SO now come to your question,the answer is very simple that the RuntimeException is also an exception, so its logically as well as design wise correct. As we know that Java is OOPs principles bases language, so here it is  basically Inheritance. Runtime exception is having all the capabilities which are there in Exception class apart from that it has overridden the exception handling behaviour from its parent and that is its unchecked behaviour. The checked exception and unchecked exceptions are just differ in the way of their handing, but rest properties of being Exception in Java is same for both. So I will say is simple OOPs design(Inheritance principle) and the relationship between the two  is logically correct.

The same thing you can observe with `Exception` and `Error` classes, now if we talk about meaning of these two in Java then exception is something which you can recover or handle but error is something which you can not recover, the only way to recover from any error is to restart the application. But then again you will see that both are extending the `Throwable` class, because both are having the same property that is both can be thrown, but their handling is different, one can be handled while other can not, thats why we have one `Exception hierarchy` and other is `Error hierarchy`.

[image]

SO for your questioin, I will say that its OOPs design, RuntimeException is inheriting from Exception class which is logically correct, Even If I were the developer of exceptions in Java, then I should have also designed these classes in the same way which are already been.

Hope It may be answer to your question.

Comment: +1 for the effort, but you don't exactly answered why Exception and RuntimeException couldn't switch places on the tree you shown. Theoretically: instead of RuntimeException overridding the checked exception handling behaviour, Exception as a subclass of RuntimeException could just extent its parent by adding "checked" behaviour.

Comment: @Atom,,,I got your question now, so suppose If we have RuntimeException as parent then logically its all child classes should also be runtime but then where we will keep the checked exception like IOException for which it is must to handle at compile time, but If we have Exception class as parent then it is telling that all its children classes will also be a type of exception, it doesn't matter whether they are chacked(compile time) or un-checked(runtime), Hope it helps you to understand,

Answer (score 2):

java is `compiled and interpreted` language

- *Java* is `compiled` to an intermediate `byte code` at `compilation` time
- Instead the byte code must be interpreted by the `JVM`  at **runtime** in order to be executed .

so this was about why checked and unchecked exception is you don't compile you can't see the `interpreted` (unchecked exception happen in here) part.

*java exception hierarchy*

[image: java exception hierarchy]

`Unchecked` Exception (we just talk about `Exception` hierarchy) in *Java* is those *Exceptions* whose handling is `NOT verified during Compile time`. These exceptions occurs because of *bad programming*. The program won’t give a compilation error. All `Unchecked` exceptions are direct sub classes of **RuntimeException** class.

[image]

Comment: I know that the above diagram is correct, but if I switched Exception and RuntimeException places, unchecked-checked behaviour would look more logically.

Comment: @Atom if you replace `RuntimeException` with `Exception` its not okay because we have checked exception its can not be done before **runtime** , super class must be have  meaningful name if you have `Runtime` super class then you can have `Exception` sub class  but here we have `Exception` its works thats why its good practice if you create the custom exception add `exception` after the `classname`

Answer (score 0):

While designing an API, developers need to take all the conditions into consideration. As Exception is considered as the deviation from the actual flow of the program. So they(**Developers who involved in designing Java API**) divided the conditions into different categories. One which can be handled at Compile Time and they(developers) have to  force who are using this API to handle at compile time only. and other which you can't expect and they need to be handle at run time(**run time/ unchecked Exception**) only and some  which cannot be handled(**Error**) at all.

Let us take an example, we are designing an application in that we need to upload a  file. we are using JAVA so in this case we can use File Input stream in order to give the  path of that file which we need to upload/download. The developers used Java pre-defined function(**File input/output stream**) as file input/output stream throws file not found exception so compiler will make the developer to handle them at compile time it self   , If the end user of this Application wants to upload a file, if he gives a path which is not available or the wrong one then that exception is occurred and handled by providing a message that file is not available then the end user can handle it easily. where as suppose if the user is using calculator application the developer will not know what kind of input end user will give so he will try to handle at run time,  if he divides any number by zero then we will give him that operation cannot be done  or infinity when we get arithmetic exception so u need change the input itself this is happening at run time after the values are submitted and the divide operation is done.